# How to find graphics card core speed, memory speed, and shader speed (if applicable) in C#?

Tags: c#, gpu, information-retrieval

I'm working on a project for my Software Engineering class at my University with a couple teammates. For details about the program we're creating [check our website](http://www.alienmania.com). It's a C# Windows Form Application developed in Visual Studio 2010.

We are having trouble retrieving some of the graphics card information we are looking for. Specifically, the graphics card's core clock speed, memory clock speed, and shader clock speed (if applicable). Through using WMI we have been able to find the graphics card brand and model ('NVIDIA' and 'GeForce GTX 465' in my personal case), the current driver, and how much dedicated RAM each graphics card attached to the local machine has.

I have searched and searched and have been unable to come up with any way to find out this information without purchasing an SDK like the CPU-Z one.

Comment: @Robusto: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @kairojya, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: That website will eventually change; could you include any relevant details in your question text?

Comment: @Roger Pate, I'm sorry, I'm new to this website. However I feel that I did state what we have tried so far, using WMI, and I stated it's limitations (restrictions) with how much graphics card specific information we are able to retrieve via the WMI. Specifically what is confusing me and my mates is what I specifically mentioned: "How to find graphics card core speed, memory speed, and shader speed (if applicable) in C#".

Comment: Those are general guidelines for all questions; you did a fairly decent job following them initially. (I was talking to Robusto as well, showing how to ask for more information rather than just tagging [homework] inappropriately.)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get at some of this information through DirectX. In the .NET world, you'd use XNA or call into native DirectX to get the video card device capabilities.

Look for "graphics caps" or "device capabilities" in the DirectX and XNA documentation.

Comment: Thanks! We will try this and see where we get.

Comment: While XNA is the premier way to program against DirectX in .NET, it is a big abstraction that isn't as powerful as the full DirectX framework. For that reason, you may want to look into SlimDX, a free and open-source .NET wrapper over DirectX. http://slimdx.org